# Convert from Object to Dictionary

Tags: object, dictionary, type-conversion

can anyone tell me the correct way to convert from Object to Dictionary

I used this way.

```
public void ReceiveFriedns(Object obj)
{

    Dictionary<string,object> ht = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    ht = obj as Dictionary<string,object>;
        }
```

But It shows 
cannot conver type from `UnityEngine.Object' to`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'

Comment: So what do you want to achieve? Currently you create a Dictionary and release it in the next line. Is `obj` of type ` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and thus a `System.Object` or a `UnityEngine.Object`?

Comment: Sure.  `Dictionary ht = Glibnix(obj);` in the Parqart programming language.

Comment: If you tag your question with the programming language which you are using (Java? Intercal? VisualBasic?), the people who can actually answer will find it sooner.